# Retrieving User Agent from Apache/Nginx Access.log

Tags: linux, bash, apache, nginx, ssh

I have the command below which prints out hits, host IP (local server/load balancer) and external IP (the one causing the hit) I would also like to print out the User Agent information alongside the information given. How can this be achieved please?

```
cat access.log | sed -e 's/^\([[:digit:]\.]*\).*"\(.*\)"$/\1 \2/' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -20
```

What I get is below...

Hits, Host IP, External IP

What I'd like if possible...

Hits,  IP (host example), External IP (causing the hit),   User Agent

`10000  192.168.1.1  148.285.xx.xx  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98 Safari/537.4`

Attached below is an excerpt from the log

```
192.168.xxx.x - - [10/Jun/2019:12:40:15 +0100] "GET /company-publications/152005 HTTP/1.1" 200 55848 "google.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.12) Gecko/20080219 Firefox/2.0.0.12 Navigator/9.0.0.6" "xx.xx.xx.xx"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If GNU AWK (`gawk`) is available, please try the following:

```
awk -v FPAT='(\"[^"]+\")|(\\[[^]]+])|([^ ]+)' '
{ gsub("\"", "", $9); gsub("\"", "", $10); print $1 " " $10 " " $9 }
' access.log | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -20
```

- The value of `FPAT` represents a regex of each field in `access.log`. That is: "string surrounded by double quotes", "string surrounded by square
  brackets" or "string separated by whitespaces".
- Then you can split each line of `access.log` into fields: `$1` for `host IP`,
  `$10` for `external IP`, and `$9` for `user agent`.

Comment: Thank you this seems to work perfectly! A separate question...are you aware of how I could potentially perform a domain lookup on the IP's presented as an addition to that `awk` command?

Comment: Good to know it is working. As for your question, `AWK` does not have a built-in command for a domain lookup. You may need to use an external command as `nslookup`.

Comment: Thanks tshiono...so I would need to run that as a separate command afterwards?

Comment: It may depend on how you would like to display the final result. If you can post a couple of sample log lines and your desired output, I may be a help to you.